# Масштабирование ресурсов и производительность

Tags: разработка-игр, дизайн, спрайт, assets

Нужно отрисовать ресурсы для игры на андроид в силе пиксель-арт среднее разрешение которых составляет `32 х 32` пикселя. Как это лучше сделать, создать ресурсы `32 х 32` и потом уже при рендеринге их на экран масштабировать до нужных разрешений или лучше создать ресурсы `32 х 32`, потом вручную их увеличить до нужного разрешения и уже рендерить их в таком формате? Как масштабирование в таком случае влияет на производительность и зависит ли это как-то от величины масштабирования?

Comment: Если это настоящий пиксель-арт, то практически никакой разницы не будет. Первый вариант будет предпочтительнее, т.к. будет требовать чуть меньше видеопамяти (которой для пиксельарта и так всегда более чем достаточно).

Comment: Что ты имеешь ввиду под настоящим пиксель-артом?

Comment: Настоящий пиксель-арт, это например  Super Mario Bros 1985 года. Там спрайты типа 16х16. При увеличении, каждый пиксель просто рисуется крупнее. Без фильтрации, без сглаживания, без нейронки-апскейла. Если у тебя такой, то вопрос тривиален - храни как нарисовано и увеличивай при рендере. Если же вопрос почем-то возник, значит у тебя что-то не тривиальное .. Показывай иллюстрации в вопросе (или в Дискорде напиши).

Comment: Да, у меня такой, отрисованы по пикселям и на экране те же пиксели только отрисованы крупнее. Хорошо, буду при рендеринге просто размеры задавать для спрайтов и все, спасибо